# Use code across multiple class files

Tags: objective-c, ios

Let's say I have this code:

```
if ([resultButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Tax"]) {

        TAXViewController *controller = [[TAXViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TAXViewController" bundle:nil];
        controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
        [controller release];

    }else if ([resultButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@""]){

        RENTViewController *controller = [[RENTViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RENTViewController" bundle:nil];
        controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
        [controller release];

    }else if //repeats a lot......
```

And I want to use this same exact code in multiple .h files. Is there a way to write the code (in only one place) and access it from other .h files without having it repeat everywhere?

So in the end I guess, I could just pass a string to that other .h/.m files and it would open the view with the matching string.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to access it from multiple classes (.h .m ?)

Comment: like instead of `[self openNewView:@"View"];` have it call fro another .h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in one class and make all of the other files you want to access it in a subclass of it.

```
@interface SomeController : BaseViewController
```

You can also WAY simplify your code

```
UIViewController *controller;
if ([resultButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Tax"])
        controller = [[TAXViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TAXViewController" bundle:nil];
else if ([resultButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@""])    
        controller = [[RENTViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RENTViewController" bundle:nil];
else if
....
//after all if-else statements
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
[controller release];
```

Comment: Ahh yes, thanks for the simplified version. Was looking for that.

Comment: Don't really understand the first thing you mentioned though. I added what I would like it to end as.

Comment: Basically, write a view controller (or whatever kind of file you're trying to put it in) that has this method in it and nothing else. Then do the thing that I put at the top of the method (add `: FileName` to the interface declaration). Then it's a subclass of that view controller so you can still do `[self callMethod]` even without the method declared.

Comment: `add : FileName` to the interface declaration -- Is this in .h or .m ?

Comment: I'm getting this: `Class method '+openCalcView:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')`

Comment: It's in the .h file. It's probably just some basic misunderstanding about how to subclass. Edit your question to have some code.